# Java Json map object child as id

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, jsonschema

I am creating a JSON mapper that will create JSON schema for my JPA database classes. I am using `mbknor-jackson-jsonSchema` that works great, but I need to serialize my subclasses as `id` only.

So far my structure is:

```
public class ModelPojo{
    private List<Table> table;
    private List<Table2> table2;
}
```

Both table classes look similar to this:

```
@Table(name = "TABLE")
public class Table extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(name = "SMTH")
    private String smth;

    @JoinColumn(name = "TABLE2")
    private Table2 table2;   //now this is where is the problem

}
```

`BaseEntity` contains integer `id` field.

The question is, is there a way to write custom std serializer that serializes table entity to have property `id_table2: "integer"`, but not the whole object?

I tried to override serialize method for `StdSerializer<BaseEntity>` which does not work, it is not called when creating the schema

Edit: I now get

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "Model Pojo",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "Table": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/Table"
      }
    }
    "Table2": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/Table2"
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Table": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "table2": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Table2"
        },
        "smth": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "Table2": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "foo": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and i want to change

```
"table2": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Table2"
        },
```

to

```
"table2_id": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
```

The structure of joined tables is much more complex, so I am trying to not manually add `@JsonIgnore` and changing it manually, but write some type of serializer that retypes the child instances of `BaseEntity` to `id`, hope it's understandable.

Comment: Try putting `@JsonIdentityInfo` onto `table2`.

Comment: Can you provide a simple data-sample illustrating what how `ModelPojo` should be serialized? And the same for standalone `Table` instance as well.

Comment: *"but write some type of serializer"* - so you want a custom serializer for these `Table` classes? OK, added this option as well.

Comment: Do you need a solution for the serialization and/or just for the JSON schema generation? the existing answers below aim at the serialization itself (and hope to be picked up by the JSON schema generator perhaps).
As the author of an alternative JSON schema generator library (victools/jsonschema-generator), I have ideas for solving the schema generation challenge. For the "real" serialization, @AlexanderIvanchenko appears to have covered it quite nicely already.

Comment: Hi @Carsten, yeah I'm aiming just for the schema serialization, thats all I really need. The answer from AlexanderIvanchenko is for the "real" serialization that works and is really good, but I cant find a way to change the schema. I'll be open to any ideas if you can share :) because I am a bit stuck atm

Comment: @konselik have you tried Thomas's suggestion of putting `@JsonIdentityInfo` on the `BaseEntity` and `@JsonIdentityReference` on the "table2" attribute in the `Table` class? Some examples are here: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-identity-reference.html
Not sure whether `mbknor` supports this though.
As mentioned before, I'm the author of a different jsonschema generator library ([`victools`](https://github.com/victools/jsonschema-generator)) and I do not yet support this out-of-the-box myaelf, but it would be achievable through configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes, I changed JSON serialization framework to victools/jsonschema-generator, which allowed me to heavily modify its serialization

I then serialized with customDefinitionProvider. It helped me to change JsonNode names and most importantly I could chose what I want to serialize through code not via Json tags.

Thanks @Carsten for great work :)

Comment: Glad it helped.

I still believe Thomas's suggestion of putting `@JsonIdentityInfo` on your `BaseEntity` and `@JsonIdentityReference` on the "table2" attribute in the `Table` class (and each similar occurrence) would be the "standard jackson way" of doing it. Some examples are here: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-identity-reference.html

I would still have to add proper support to the library, in order to avoid the need for the extensive custom schema generation you currently have to do. Maybe assuming it's used like here with "alwaysAsId=true" should be simple.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ignore all properties of your domain entities `Table` and `Table2` apart from `id` (inherited from `BaseEntity`) while serializing `ModelPojo` but at the same time you need **all** the properties `Table` and `Table2` to be reflected while serializing them as standalone objects, you can introduce a method inside `ModelPojo` which to instruct the Jackson how to dial with this class.

```
public class ModelPojo {
    private List<Table> table;
    private List<Table2> table2;
    
    public List<Map<String, Integer>> getTable() {
        return extractIds(table);
    }

    public List<Map<String, Integer>> getTable2() {
        return extractIds(table2);
    }
    
    private List<Map<String, Integer>> extractIds(List<? extends BaseEntity> list) {
        return list.stream().map(t -> Map.of("id", t.getId())).toList();
    }
}
```

In the absence of real getters, `getTable()` and `getTable2()` would be used by Jackson. No data-binding annotations required.

But you might need **normal getters**, that's understandable.

In such case, the approach described above can be improved by introducing a single method returning a `Map` (*as a replacement of* `getTable()` *and* `getTable2()`) annotated with [`@JsonAnyGetter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnyGetter.html) (to make Jackson aware of this method) and [`@JsonUnwrapped`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) (to flatten the contents of this map).

The fields `table` and `table2` should be annotated with `@JsonIgnore`.

```
public class ModelPojo {
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Table> table;
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Table2> table2;
    
    @JsonAnyGetter
    @JsonUnwrapped
    public Map<String, List<Map<String, Integer>>> getAll() {
        return Map.of(
            "table", extractIds(table),
            "table2", List.of()
        );
    }
    
    private List<Map<String, Integer>> extractIds(List<? extends BaseEntity> list) {
        return list.stream().map(t -> Map.of("id", t.getId())).toList();
    }

    // getters
}
```

> I am trying to not manualy add `@JsonIgnore` and changing it manually, but write some type of serializer that retypes the child instances of `BaseEntity` to `id`

Sure, you can implement a custom serializer for these fields as well.

For that, you need extend `JsonSerializer` class and implement its `abstract` method `serialize()`.

```
public class TableSerializer extends JsonSerializer<List<? extends BaseEntity>> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(List<? extends BaseEntity> list,
                          JsonGenerator gen,
                          SerializerProvider serializers)
                          throws IOException {
        
        gen.writeObject(extractIds(list));
    }

    private List<Map<String, Integer>> extractIds(List<? extends BaseEntity> list) {
        return list.stream().map(t -> Map.of("id", t.getId())).toList();
    }
}
```

A now we need to instruct Jackson to apply this serializer by specifying it as a value of [`using`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html#using--) attribute of the [`@JsonSerialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html) annotation.

```
public class ModelPojo {
    @JsonSerialize(using = TableSerializer.class)
    private List<Table> table;
    @JsonSerialize(using = TableSerializer.class)
    private List<Table2> table2;

    // getters
}
```

Comment: Hi, amazing answer!!! In 99% of times I think you would be correct but at this time I came to conclusion that the library I chose works in ways I cant really do this. The JSON serialize method is not picked up correctly and as a result nothing really changes. But I really appreciate your time and willingness to help

Answer (score -1):

In table2 you can write `@JsonIgnore` on the top field which you do not want to serialize it will not send it in json response. You can do it for all other fields than id

Comment: The issue with that is that if I serialize it as standalone class (example of Table2) it has to have the fields

Comment: You can write at the top of fields in Table2 which you want to ignore. It will work . However, there are other ways too to do it on class level. Below guide will help you in acheiving this:
[Ignore fields while serializing](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization)